# Apache 2.4: Public Subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, authorization

I'm currently upgrading to Apache 2.4.

What puzzles me right now is how to create a public subdirectory using .htaccess only. The outer directory is protected by `AuthType Basic`

Previously, the directory contained the following .htaccess:

```
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```

I'm at a loss at how to reproduce this in Apache 2.4. I tried any combination of the following, without luck:

```
AuthType None
Require all granted
AuthMerging Or
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're seeing ? What error messages do you see, what did you expect, are there any relevant log messages ?

Comment: Expected behavior: No login prompt upon accessing the subdirectory. Actual: Login prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this here and it works for me. Check that the `.htaccess` file is being read for each directory; perhaps enable authentication on the subdirectory temporarily with a different `AuthName` so you can verify.

Here's my setup, in case you find it useful. The directory with auth enabled is `authtest`; its subdirectory `noauth` has authentication disabled.

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Debian)
Server built:   Jan  2 2014 01:47:52
$ cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/allow-htaccess-authtest.conf 
<Directory /var/www/html/authtest>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
$ cat /var/www/html/authtest/.htaccess 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "ahoy hoy"
AuthUserFile /home/fission/htpasswd
Require valid-user
$ cat /var/www/html/authtest/noauth/.htaccess 
AuthType None
Require all granted
```

That syntax was pulled directly from [the Apache docs for `mod_authn_core`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype)

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does work. In the meantime, I checked everything again and found I had the authentication defined twice, in .htaccess and also in a `<Location "/">` block in the virtual host config. According to [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging), `<Location>` takes precedence over (almost) everything. Which is why I was unable to override it using .htaccess.